# Azure multitenant app cant access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I try login to Azure AD web app and when i do it with user inside my tenant its ok,
but when login other user i get

AADSTS50020: User account '*******' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application 'a1eda862-65fb-4f90-8482-06151f5c7abc' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Login Url : 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=a1eda862-65fb-4f90-8482-06151f5c7abc&response_type=id_token+code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:44302/&response_mode=form_post&scope=openid+profile&state=12345&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7&resource=https://management.azure.com/

[Tenant settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh7my.png)

Answer (score 1):

Few things to check -

1. Based on the error you shared, it seems you're logged in with some Microsoft account like live.com/hotmail etc. Are you doing that intentionally or just happened to be logged in and getting confused by that? If you do want to login with a Microsoft account other than a usual organizational account, then as the error says, you need to add that account to your AzureAD tenant as an external user.

> AADSTS50020: User account '*******' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant

2. For any other organizational user, i.e. user from a different AzureAD tenant than the one where this application is registered, you will first need to go through the consent process. You may have done it already or not. 
   More details on that process here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** 
You wanted to use a personal account within a multi-tenant application to get a token for the "https://management.core.windows.net" API

**Scope:** 
We will focus on this issue and consider it as resolved once we provide you with the reason that Personal accounts cannot be used against a v1 multi-tenant application.
Alternatively, we will consider this case resolved if we confirm that the problem is caused by a third-party application or is by-design.
This agreed resolution statement describes the specific conditions where we will close this case.  Please let me know if you do not agree with this scope.

**Cause:** 
For multi-tenant applications in v1 you can only use an organizational account and not a personal one. That happens because for personal ones you will be logged authenticated by the “Live” endpoints and not by Azure endpoints, also because we are sending the user to the “common” endpoint and in there we do not know in which directory you want to sign in.

**Resolution:** 
Having a multi-tenant application and sign-in users with personal and organizational accounts can be covered by the Azure AD V2 endpoints, nevertheless the v2 has some limitations right now and one of them is that you could only get a token for Microsoft Graph API and not for https://management.core.windows.net. We plan to implement all APIs that are available in v1 also in v2, but as for now cannot be used to acquire a token for such API.